# Why I dont get array in template?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-click` method `showSchedules()` that calls AJAX:

```
$scope.showSchedules = function () {
                $scope.loadCalendar = true;
                appointmentService.getSchedule().then(function (response) {
                    calendarService.set(response.data.calendar, function () {


                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.refleshCalendars();
                            $scope.loadCalendar = false;
                            console.log($scope.events);

                        }, 100);

                    });
                });
            };
```

Inside this method you can see: `console.log($scope.events);`
It gives me filled array by objects.

When I do `{{events}}` in trmplate HTML I get `[]`.

Why I get empty array?

**HTML code:**

```
<div ng-controller="ScheduleController as vmx">
    {{events}}
    <mwl-calendar
        events="events"
        view="vmo.calendarView"
        view-title="vmo.calendarTitle"
        current-day="vmo.calendarDay"
        on-event-click="vmo.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
        on-event-times-changed="vmo.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); 
            calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; 
            calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
        auto-open="true"
        day-view-start="06:00"
        day-view-end="23:00"
        day-view-split="30"
        cell-modifier="vmo.modifyCell(calendarCell)">
    </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you fill this events?

Comment: so if you're sure that your template is good. It looks correct. So try to write `$scope.events2 = angular.copy($scope.events)` and check events2 in your template.

Comment: are you actually putting the `{{events}}` in template that has same scope as `$scope.events`?

Comment: I demonstrated my HTML code with `{{events}}`

Comment: {{vmx.events}} !!!!!

Comment: If `{{vmx.events}}` is not working my next question would be where are you actually setting `$scope.events`?

Comment: I set `$scope.events` in top of controller: `$scope.events = [];` and there is function `showSchedules()` after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `{{vmx.events}}` because you are using the `controller as` annotation

> Using `controller as` makes it obvious which controller you are
>   accessing in the template when multiple controllers apply to an
>   element.

[ngController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) (Search for ***controller as***)

Comment: I tried `{{vmx.events}}` inside HTML template, is empty `[]` too

Comment: Also I removed `as` in controller

Comment: I would quickly test that events is bound correctly by setting `$scope.events = 'foo'` when you do that `console.log` if the value doesn't update on your view you have a binding problem, otherwise you probably have an issue with a the `events` being empty when you set `$scope.events`